# sum of two field in two table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have four tables in the database as follows:

**tblInvoice:**

```
 invcid,customerid,invoicedate
```

**tblInvcDetail:**

```
ID,invcid,item,itemprice,itemquantity
```

**tblPay:**

```
payid,invcid,paydate
```

**tblPayDetail:**

```
payid,amount
```

I need to create a list of invoiceid, invoicedate, (sum of itemprice*itemquantity), (sum of amount) where userid is given.
I tried this query:

```
SELECT tblinvoice.invcid,
       tblinvoice.invcdate,
       Sum(tblinvcdetail.itemprice * tblinvcdetail.itemquantity) AS SumOfInvoice,
       Sum(tblpaydetail.amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM   ((tblinvoice
         LEFT JOIN tblpay
           ON tblinvoice.invcid = tblpay.invcid)
        LEFT JOIN tblinvcdetail
          ON tblinvoice.invcid = tblinvcdetail.invcid)
       LEFT JOIN tblpaydetail
         ON tblpay.payid = tblpaydetail.payid
GROUP  BY tblinvoice.invcid,
          tblinvoice.invcdate;
```

But the result is not quite correct
Please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Sample data:

**tblInvoice:**

```
invcid   customerid invcdate        |invcsum(manualy calculated)
18      8             6/30/2012     |$140,000
39      8             7/12/2012     |$170,000
40      8             7/12/2012     |$80,000
43      8             7/14/2012     |$80,000
44      8             7/14/2012     |$80,000
45      8             7/15/2012     |$700,000
46      8             7/17/2012     |$180,000
```

**tblInvcDetail:**

```
ID  invccid  itemname       itemprice   itemquantity
19  18              X           $70,000     2
92  39              Y           $80,000     1
93  39              Z           $90,000     1
94  40              Y           $80,000     1
97  43              Y           $80,000     1
98  44              Y           $80,000     1
99  45              W           $700,000       1
100 46              Y           $80,000     1
101 46              U           $100,000       1
```

**tblPay:**

```
payid   invcid      paydate           |AmountSUM(Manually Calculated)     
35          18         7/11/2012    |$120,000
40          18         7/12/2012    |$147,000
41          40         7/12/2012    |$84,000
44          44         7/14/2012    |$84,000
46          45         7/15/2012    |$700,000
```

**tblPayDetail:**

```
payid       amount
35          $100,000
35          $20,000
40          $147,000
41          $84,000
44          $84,000
46          $700,000
```

**And finally the query result is:**

```
invcid  invcdate    SumOfInvoice    SumOfAmount
18      6/30/2012   $420,000.00     $267,000.00
39      7/12/2012   $170,000.00 
40      7/12/2012   $80,000.00      $84,000.00
43      7/14/2012   $80,000.00  
44      7/14/2012   $80,000.00      $84,000.00
45      7/15/2012   $700,000.00     $700,000.00
46      7/17/2012   $180,000.00
```

You can see that the calculation is wrong in the first row (SumOfInvoice column)
and the rest is correct!

Comment: Some of the rows, and in all cases the first row Calculation result is wrong.I did some testing and it seems The contents of the table tblpaydetail affected on calculation of tblinvoicedetail!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT a.invcid,
       a.invcdate,
       a.sumofinvoice,
       b.sumofamount
FROM   (SELECT ti.invcid,
               ti.invcdate,
               SUM(td.itemprice * td.itemquantity) AS SumOfInvoice
        FROM   tblinvoice AS ti
               LEFT JOIN tblinvcdetail AS td
                      ON ti.invcid = td.invcid
        GROUP  BY ti.invcid,
                  ti.invcdate) a
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT tp.invcid,
                         SUM(tpd.amount) AS SumOfAmount
                  FROM   tblpay AS tp
                         LEFT JOIN tblpaydetail AS tpd
                                ON tp.payid = tpd.payid
                  GROUP  BY tp.invcid) b
              ON a.invcid = b.invcid
```