# Get SUM of two fields in 2 different related tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to get the SUM of the `amount` column in two related tables.

**Invoices Table:**

```
-----------------------------------------
| id  | student_id  | created | updated |
-----------------------------------------
|  5  |     25      | date    | date    |
-----------------------------------------
```

**Invoice Items Table:**

```
------------------------------
| id  | invoice_id  | amount |
------------------------------
|  1  |     5       | 250    |
------------------------------
|  2  |     5       | 100    |
------------------------------
|  3  |     5       | 40     |
------------------------------
```

**Payments Table:**

```
------------------------------
| id  | invoice_id  | amount |
------------------------------
|  1  |     5       | 100    |
------------------------------
|  2  |     5       | 290    |
------------------------------
```

**Desired Output:**

```
--------------------------------------
| id  | invoiceTotal  | paymentTotal |
--------------------------------------
|  1  |     390       |    390       |
--------------------------------------
```

**The query I've tried**

```
SELECT 
    i.id,
    sum(ii.amount) as invoiceTotal,
    sum(p.amount) as paymentTotal
FROM 
    invoices i
LEFT JOIN 
    invoice_items ii ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN 
    payments p ON i.id = p.invoice_id
WHERE 
    i.student_id = '25'
GROUP BY 
    i.id
```

What this seems to do is calculate the sum of the payments properly but the `invoice_items.amount` appears to have been duplicated by 6 (which is the number of `payments` there are).

I have read similar questions on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11535215/sum-of-two-field-in-two-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744241/want-to-get-sum-of-2-different-columns-from-2-different-tables-and-want-to-displ) but the examples are so much more complex than what I'm trying to do and I can't figure out what to put where.

Comment: @Stidgeon Ok, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join causes a problem with cartesian products.  If a student has multiple invoice items and payments, then the totals will be wrong.

One approach that works best for all invoices is a `union all`/`group by` approach:

```
select i.id, sum(invoiceTotal) as invoiceTotal, sum(paymentTotal) as paymentTotal
from ((select i.id, 0 as invoiceTotal, 0 as paymentTotal
       from invoices i
      ) union all
      (select ii.invoiceId, sum(ii.amount) as invoiceTotal, NULL
       from invoiceitems ii
       group by ii.invoiceId
      ) union all
      (select p.invoiceId, 0, sum(p.amount) as paymentTotal
       from payments p
       group by p.invoiceId
      )
     ) iip
group by id;
```

For a single student, I would recommend correlated subqueries:

```
select i.id,
       (select sum(ii.amount)
        from invoiceitems ii
        where ii.invoiceid = i.id
       ) as totalAmount,
       (select sum(p.amount)
        from payment p
        where p.invoiceid = i.id
       ) as paymentAmount
from invoices i
where i.studentid = 25;
```

Comment: Thank you. The second example does exactly what I want to do.